# Measures on the Sigma Algebra generated by a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'd like to prove the last part of an exercise in my book. The quetion is as follows

Let $(X,\Sigma ,\mu )$ be a measure space and define $$\mu '(M):=\inf\left\{ \mu (A):M\subset A\in \Sigma  \right\} $$
as the outer measure ( I already showed that this is an outer measure). $M\in { 2 }^{ X }\setminus \Sigma $ and  $\mu'(M)>0$ further let $\Sigma_M$ be the sigma algebra generated by $M$. Find all measures ${ \mu  }_{ M }$ on ${ \Sigma  }_{ M }$ with ${ { \mu  }_{ M } }_{ |\Sigma  }={ \mu  }$.

My first question would be if there is a typo in my book shouldn't it be ${ { \mu  }_{ M } }_{ |\Sigma  }={ \mu'  }$?

My second question is how do I construct such measures i can't even think of possible canidates. Could someone provide a hint? I'm lost on this one.

Comment: technically it can be seen as one yes but i don't see why this fact helps? And for your tip i don't quite see yet why  ${ \mu'  }$ restricted to the sigma algebra equals ${ \mu  }$

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the trace of a sigma algebra but reading the wikipedia definition the trace and the generated sigma algebra are somewhat related. For me the generated sigma algebra is the intersection of all sigma algebras that contain the "generator" set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, we already have a measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ so it is actually logical to ask for measures on the larger $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma_M$ (which IMHO should be desribed as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\Sigma \cup \{M\}$, not as a trace or some such notion; just the "$\sigma$-algebra generated by $M$" makes no sense in this context: that is just the $4$-set $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, X, M, X\setminus M\}$ and is unrelated to $\Sigma$), that are extensions of $\mu$. 
So $(\mu_M)_{|_{\Sigma}} = \mu$ seems the right condition to me.

The prime candidate for such a $\mu_M$ is of course the given $\mu'$ which coincides with $\mu$ on $\Sigma$ already (for $M \in \Sigma$ the infimum described is a minimum attained at $M$ itself..), but then we get into Carathéodory theorem realms, whether this $\mu'$ is actually a well-defined measure on $\Sigma_M$, look up theorems around that.